# Convert SQL Query to Linq Query but unable to do

Tags: c#, sql

```
SELECT SY.* FROM Survey SY WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN AssetPurity AP WITH (NOLOCK) ON 
   AP.[LocationId] = SY.LocationId AND AP.SesionUID = SY.SessionUID AND 
   AP.SceneTypeCode != 5 AND  AP.SceneSubTypeCode != 1
WHERE SY.LocationId = 1 AND SY.SurveyStatusId = 1 AND SY.IsDeleted = 0 
AND SY.SurveyDate >= curPeriod.startPeriodDate.Value 
AND SY.SurveyDate <= curPeriod.endPeriodDate.Value
```

i am trying to convert this query to linq but unable

Comment: What have you tried and why it doesn't work?

Comment: You can't convert the `with (nolock)` part into LINQ query.

Comment: ok no issue can we do it without nolock part if yes then please suggest me

Comment: `WITH (NOLOCK)` is invariably a bug used to cover up another bug, causing a far greater problem. `NOLOCK` doesn't mean go fast, it means `read dirty and duplicate data while randomly crashing`. Fix the actual performance bug and don't try to use LINQ as if it was SQL. It's not. It's the query language of an ORM like NHibernate or EF Core. It's the *ORM* that generates JOINs from relations

Comment: @ShailendraPal why did you think that NOLOCK would help in anything? What bug were you trying to avoid? Missing indexes? Long running transactions? Locks over the entire table? All of those have different fixes and none involves NOLOCK

Comment: i am just trying how we can i write this sql query in linq

Answer (score 0):

Here is the equivalent LINQ query of your SQL without `nolock` parts.

```cs
var query = ( from sy in context.Survey
              join ap in context.AssetSecurity
                       .Where(p=> p.SceneTypeCode != 5 && p.SceneSubTypeCode != 1) on
           new {sy.LocationId, sy.SessionUID} equals new {ap.LocationId, ap.SessionUID}
             where sy.LocationId = 1 && sy.SurveyStatusId = 1 && sy.IsDeleted = 0 
             && sy.SurveyDate >= curPeriod.startPeriodDate.Value 
             && sy.SurveyDate <= curPeriod.endPeriodDate.Value
             select sy
)
```

The trick is to move the constant parts into the where clause and use the anonymous type for multi-conditional join.

Comment: i do wonder where this `curPeriod.startPeriodDate.Value` came from. if its a `Nullable` you might hit something unexpected. it would be far safer to pass the `where` parameters in a chain after checking its value is not `null`.

Comment: @BagusTesa it seemed to me they are not part of the SQL as they look like nullable `DateTime` so I used them as is.